# How do I find Element inside TemplateRef Return nativeElment 'Comment'

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
 <ng-template #TabContent>
   <div class="scroll">
    chat Section. 
   </div>
                
 </ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
@ViewChild(TabContent)TabContent:TemplateRef<any>

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  const childNode = this.TabContent.elementRef.nativeElement;
  console.log("this is child",childNode);
  return 'Comment' not the html element it embeds   
}
```

Problem

***Scroll down on new Message***

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have created chat app inside ng template ... Issue in scroll on new message ... In component.ts  i have used viewchild for template ref but tenplate ref return comment how can access html ...for scroll function call to move scroll down to new message ...this.viewchlid(ref).elementRef.NativeElement.scrollHeight return undefined ....